# Django static files - can't find nested files

Tags: django

It was working quite nicely, but not any more.

I have the following file structure and i'm trying to find the following file:

```
[thisProject]
    ----blog
        ----static
            ----blog
                ----scss
                    ----slick.scss  [<---cant find this file]
            ----platform
```

I've tried `python manage.py findstatic slick.scss -v3`

and I receive the following:

```
Looking in the following locations:
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtaildocs\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailsnippets\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailusers\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailimages\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailembeds\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailforms\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\blog\static
  D:\git\thisProject\thisProject\env\lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\providers\facebook\static
  d:\home\yourusername\webapps\skunkworks_static_rockitt
```

if you note the 3rd line from the bottom - it's looking in the correct directory, but it still can't find it.

My settings are as follows:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (


    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    more apps here,
)
DEBUG = True
```

**any ideas why it can't find this file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will not look in subdirectories of your app's static directory unless you tell it to:

`python manage.py findstatic blog/scss/slick.scss`.

This is deliberate, so that you can override core templates by mirroring their directory structure inside your own app.

Incidentally, this namespacing is a [good idea generally](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files):

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our static files directly in my_app/static/ (rather than creating another my_app subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself.